# Query only the selected values from ACF Relationship Field

Tags: html, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need to query only the selected Testimonials. But using my code it queries all Testimonials including the unselected testimonials. (see screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/NrAtjPAoiUq ). Only the 3 selected Testimonials should displayed in the page.

Here is my code:

```
            <?php 

        wp_reset_postdata(); 

        $posts = get_field('testimonial_test');

        if( $posts ): ?>

            <?php foreach( $posts as $post): ?>
                <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
              <div class="item">
              <blockquote>
              <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="test_box">
                <?php the_content();?>
              </div>
                <h5><?php the_title();?></span></h5>

                </div>
                </div>
                </blockquote>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Can some give an advice what am i missing in this code? Thanks!

Comment: Try using a variable other than $posts, something like $testimonials, then do `foreach( $testimonials as $post ):`. Also you shouldn't need to reset postdata before the loop, just after.

Comment: try to dump the post id and check if it retrieves the correct one